# Does nested resource acquisition require special handling in Java?

Tags: java, exception, nested

First of all, yes, try-with-resource fixes any of these questions... but I can't see how this exactly works without it.

Let's look at this code from the java documentation as an example, which can be found  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```java
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path)
                                                     throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    }
}
```

Now, the resource is released on `br.close()` if it was acquired. However,

- What happens if `new FileReader(path)` succeeds and then `new BufferedReader(...)` throws an exception?
- How does java guarantee that the `FileReader` is closed?
- Is it guaranteed that creating a `BufferedReader` on an already opened `FileReader` will always succeed? If so, why is that method declared as throwing an `IOException`?

Or should we instead be writing the following to make sure that situation doesn't happen?

```java
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path)
                                                     throws IOException {

    FileReader fr;

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            return br.readLine();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) br.close();
        }
    finally {
        // Implements closeable, so it is ok if we call it twice.
        if (fr != null) fr.close();
    }
}
```

Of course, using try-with-resources, this nested mess disappears nonetheless, since we can declare multiple resources in the same statement. But I always see myself writing try-with-resources as a way to avoid thinking at all about exactly this situation, and trying to find a solution online I really couldn't.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can give ARM (Automatic Resource Management) a try - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials are often out of date or don't describe good practice.

If we look at the first piece of code you quoted, `br` can never be `null`. The `if ( )` can be removed. This was probably caused by previous code by previous code mixing to `finally` with a `catch`. If a `try` statement has both `finally` and a `catch` it is probably wrong and almost certainly doing something ill advised. Typically you'd see a `null` dance going on and at least one obvious bug.

The received wisdom on this issue is that `BufferedReader` will only fail if something has gone horribly wrong with your entire process. Perhaps out of memory or the stack have overflowed. If you get those sorts of exceptions you probably want to bail out of altogether.

The pedantic way of writing the code without try-with-resource is:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    return br.readLine();
} finally {
    fr.close();
}
```

However, in some case you may get this wrong. Considered `BufferWriter`. You've forgotten to `flush` that, haven't you? I mean, I would. If you closed that in a `finally`, it wouldn't have been a problem. Also some decorators are resources themselves. For instance, they may have a native implementation that uses non-garbage collected memory. That isn't necessarily documented.

Closing both resource and decorator isn't difficult, but does kind of head towards the right without try with resource.

```
// (Using same example even though it doesn't matter here - imaging a Writer)
FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
} finally {
    fr.close();
}
```

Comment: So, the second way you point out would be the correct one in java 6? Or is there any extra missteps that might happen when the `closeable` object is different that the ones in my example? (`BufferedReader` and `FileReader`). My point is that, in general, I can't find the pattern that should always work for all resources...

Answer (score 1):

Look in java source code at implementation of `close()` for `BufferedReader`.

```
 * @see FileReader
 * @see InputStreamReader
 * @see java.nio.file.Files#newBufferedReader
 *
 * @author      Mark Reinhold
 * @since       1.1
 */

public class BufferedReader extends Reader {

private Reader in;

...
 public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (in == null)
            return;
        try {
            in.close();
        } finally {
            in = null;
            cb = null;
        }
    }
}
...
  /**
 * Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses an input buffer of
 * the specified size.
 *
 * @param  in   A Reader
 * @param  sz   Input-buffer size
 *
 * @exception  IllegalArgumentException  If {@code sz <= 0}
 */
public BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz) {
    super(in);
    if (sz <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    this.in = in;
    cb = new char[sz];
    nextChar = nChars = 0;
}

/**
 * Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses a default-sized
 * input buffer.
 *
 * @param  in   A Reader
 */
public BufferedReader(Reader in) {
    this(in, defaultCharBufferSize);
}
```

so close() is taken care of Reader (FileReader here) and set it to null.

Simply `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))` is fine

> Does nested resource acquisition require special handling in Java?

here: NO

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if new FileReader(path) succeeds and then new BufferedReader(...) throws an exception?

The `BufferedReader` constructor doesn't throw exceptions. Particularly, it doesn't involve any filesystem operations, so it doesn't throw IOException.

> How does java guarantee that the FileReader is closed?

The BufferedReader's close method closes the underlying FileReader.

> Is it guaranteed that creating a BufferedReader on an already opened FileReader will always succeed? If so, why is that method declared as throwing an IOException?

You're focusing on the wrong thing. `readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock` is marked with `throws IOException` because every method or constructor invoked besides the BufferedReader constructor can throw IOException. `readline`, `close`, and the `FileReader` constructor can all throw.

---

If both the FileReader and BufferedReader constructors could fail, and if both objects needed to be closed separately, then you would need two `try`s.

Comment: hmm, yeah... That is the key I guess, `BufferedReader` can't fail once `FileReader` succeeds, and if `FileReader` failed, we don't need to close it

Answer (score 0):

You can use try with resources instead of releasing resources individually. Please look the below code.

```
try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""))) {

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but of course it does work with try-with-resources, the whole point was what is the best pattern when you don't have access to that feature of java7 (i.e., your company has legacy code they think is too expensive to clean out to upgrade)

Comment: For that you must close the resources on the outer finally block rather writing finally block inside the try.